# "nonce" is always return 0

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js

I used `"web3.eth.getTransaction(address)"` to do transactions.

After, It is not working with error

> "Node error: {"code":-32000,"message":"nonce too low"}"

After checking nonce value, it always returned 0.

I use

- OS ubuntu
- node v8.10.1
- web3 3.5.2
- network ropsten
- address 0xDff27954C1Cf3C5b2081ac45505d3c9205a410d1 in ropsten / ether

and this is my code

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(senderAddr, 'pending').then(function(count) {
      count += 1;
      var transactionObject = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(count.toString(16)),
        from: sender,
        to: receiver,
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(15000),
        value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether'))),
        data: '',
        chainId: 3
      }
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What node are you connected to? When I ask Infura's Ropsten node for the transaction count for that account, it returns 5.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the node you're connected is giving you a wrong `nonce`.

FYI, make sure you delete the `count += 1;` line.  Because `nonce` is `0-indexed`

Answer (score 0):

If in the local blockchain, the address that you are using to deploy the contract has not been used before, you will get nonce 0.